# NHibernate, ISession per presenter, multiple presenters open

Tags: .net, nhibernate, mvp

How would you solve the following situation: the app is MVP based (WinForms) and at the same time I can have multiple presenters showing. Each presenter has a session attached, and open during the lifetime of the presenter.

If I load an entity in one presenter and pass it through to another to show it, and if that entity has some collection to it, I get "Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions".

Now, am I doing something wrong with my architecture? I don't see a problem with mutiple sessions open (connections are of course not open all the time).

Any opinions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you retrieve data from a database using NHibernate, **the returned entity objects get associated to the `ISession` instance that materialized them**. All subsequent operations involving the database on any of those objects must be performed through the same `ISession` instance. This includes fetching associated collections of entities via lazy loading.

One way to solve this problem is **making sure that any collections associated to the entity object are already populated before passing it to another session**. There are a couple of ways of achieving this:

1. You could load the collections after the entity object has been retrieved by simply accessing their relative properties on the entity object, thus **triggering lazy loading**.
2. You could retrieve the entity object together with its associated collections through **eager loading**.

Note that in both cases you should completely detach the entity object from its session before passing it to another one by calling the `ISession.Evict` method.

Comment: Yes, as I see it this is the best way of doing things with this patterns (session per presenter), alternative could be that I pass Id of the object instead of the actual entity, and then leave it to the second presenter's session to get a copy of that entity; but Evict is cleaner for now. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Denis, I have been fighting exactly the same problem in an MVP Winforms application and the best way we could find to solve the problem reliably was to move to a "Persistent conversations" model rather than "Session Per Presenter".

This previous questions contains many of the links you will need

[Example of nhibernate winform application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168892/example-of-nhibernate-winform-application)

Comment: I've looked into Session per Bussiness Transaction before, but hadn't time to implement and really test this pattern. As soon as find time I will upgrade my architecture, because I can see clear benefits of having something like that. I'm a little careful about integrating other people code blindly, althought I'm sure that uNhAddins is really high quality code and work. For now, I stick to session per presenter and Evict calls Enrico suggested.