# NHibernate fetch old values instead of new values from Db

Tags: nhibernate

I use Nhibernate in a windows application. at run time I close the form and then i change the data in Db manually so after opening the form, it shows the old values instead of new entered values. it shows new values just when i close all program (killing process) and start application again.

this question was already asked by Kristoffer but there was no accepted answer for that.

please lead me to solve this problem.

thanks

Comment: After some try and error I could solve the problem by using Session.Clear() method.

Comment: Are you using a single ISession for the lifetime of the application?

Comment: @lan Nelson: yes, cause some reason i use a single ISeesion for whole life time of the application.

Answer (score 4):

You should read some texts that explain how the NHibernate session (first level cache) works, otherwise you will get big problems using it.

Answer (score 2):

To me it sounds like you are keeping a session around for longer than needed. I would recommend the following article, it is essential reading for anyone creating a winforms application using nhibernate.

[MSDN Magazine - Building a Desktop To-Do Application with NHibernate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

On a windows application you should be using session per presenter.

This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168892/example-of-nhibernate-winform-application) has some good answers that might provide you with a solution.

Also a good Google phrase is "session per presenter"

The NHibernate [cookbook](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9781849513043/sessions-and-transactions/ch03lvl1sec03) also has a good example (although you will need to pay for this)